# Accessing snakemake variables in subscript

Tags: python, snakemake

I have a Snakemake workflow where a function from one python file is called in another python file, similar to the following:

```py
### Snakefile
rule test:
    input:
        "input.file"
    output:
        "output.file"
    script:
        "test_script.py"

### script.py
from test_subscript import run_test

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_file = snakemake.input[0]
    run_test()

### subscript.py
def run_test():
    out_file = snakemake.output[0]
    with open(out_file, "w") as f:
        f.write("Test")
```

Now, when I execute the workflow, the `snakemake.input` variable can be accessed from within `script.py`, but I cannot access the `snakemake.output` variable in `subscript.py`. A workaround would be to pass all required snakemake variables to the `run_test()` function, but that quickly gets complicated.

Is there a more convenient way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convenient way to do that is to make the scripts agnostic of Snakemake. These scripts should be called from any shell. In this case you need to provide the filenames as command line parameters:

```
### Snakefile
rule test:
    input:
        "input.file"
    output:
        "output.file"
    shell:
        "test_script.py {input} {output}"
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! However I was hoping that I can avoid passing everything through the entire hierarchy, especially when also setting several snakemake `params`.